# Save generated Word file with unique name (mailmerge)

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word, mailmerge

I need help with my macro. I need to save the generated Word file via mail merge.

```
Sub RunMerge()

Dim wd As Object
Dim wdocSource As Object

Dim strWorkbookName As String

On Error Resume Next
Set wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If wd Is Nothing Then
    Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0

Set wdocSource = wd.Documents.Open("C:\Users\admin\Desktop\New folder (2)\G706014 ver.7.0.docx")

strWorkbookName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name

wdocSource.Mailmerge.MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters

wdocSource.Mailmerge.OpenDataSource _
        Name:=strWorkbookName, _
        AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
        Revert:=False, _
        Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
        Connection:="Data Source=" & strWorkbookName & ";Mode=Read", _
        SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Mailing$`"

With wdocSource.Mailmerge
    .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
    .SuppressBlankLines = True
    With .DataSource
        .FirstRecord = wdDefaultFirstRecord
        .LastRecord = wdDefaultLastRecord
    End With
    .Execute Pause:=False
End With

wd.Visible = True
wdocSource.Close SaveChanges:=False

Set wdocSource = Nothing
Set wd = Nothing

End Sub
```

This macro just generate the file but doesn't save it.

Can somebody update it?

**But the name of the save file has to be value of Excel file, worksheet `mailing`, cell A2**

Destination for saving is: `C:\Users\admin\Desktop\New folder (2)\docs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added this in your code :

```
Dim PathToSave As String
PathToSave = "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\New folder (2)\docs\" & Sheets("mailing").Range("A2").Value2 & ".docx"
'PathToSave = "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\New folder (2)\docs\Merge_Mail_" & Replace(Replace(Now(), "/", "-"), ":", ".") & ".docx"
If Dir(PathToSave, 0) <> vbNullString Then
    wd.FileDialog(FileDialogType:=msoFileDialogSaveAs).Show
Else
    wd.activedocument.SaveAs2 PathToSave, wdFormatDocumentDefault
End If
```

Here is the full code :

```
Sub RunMerge()

Dim wd As Object, _
    wdocSource As Object, _
    PathToSave As String

Dim strWorkbookName As String

On Error Resume Next
Set wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If wd Is Nothing Then
    Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0

Set wdocSource = wd.Documents.Open("C:\Users\admin\Desktop\New folder (2)\G706014 ver.7.0.docx")

strWorkbookName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name

wdocSource.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters

wdocSource.MailMerge.OpenDataSource _
        Name:=strWorkbookName, _
        AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
        Revert:=False, _
        Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
        Connection:="Data Source=" & strWorkbookName & ";Mode=Read", _
        SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Mailing$`"

With wdocSource.MailMerge
    .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
    .SuppressBlankLines = True
    With .DataSource
        .FirstRecord = wdDefaultFirstRecord
        .LastRecord = wdDefaultLastRecord
    End With
    .Execute Pause:=False
End With

PathToSave = "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\New folder (2)\docs\" & Sheets("mailing").Range("A2").Value2 & ".docx"
'PathToSave = "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\New folder (2)\docs\Merge_Mail_" & Replace(Replace(Now(), "/", "-"), ":", ".") & ".docx"
If Dir(PathToSave, 0) <> vbNullString Then
    wd.FileDialog(FileDialogType:=msoFileDialogSaveAs).Show
Else
    wd.activedocument.SaveAs2 PathToSave, wdFormatDocumentDefault
End If

wd.Visible = True
wdocSource.Close SaveChanges:=False

Set wdocSource = Nothing
Set wd = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: What you mean with this condition under "PathToSave" ?

Comment: It is to know if the file already exists or not. You need the full path to save a doc, so there is both the name in Excel and the Path to the folder where to save the file. And if the file already exists there with the same name, it will prompt a Dialog to let you precise where or how you want to save it!
Is the whole code working for you?

Comment: Oh so, It´s a good idea but it doesn´t work. I don´t know, but I have empty folder and it shows me a window "save as"

Comment: My bad, I just invert the statements inside the `If ... End If`. Give it a try now! ;)

Comment: I was used to have this with the `If ...=... Then` and yet most of the time I use `If ...<>... Then`
Enjoy this site, and don't forget to upvote Q&A that you find useful! ;)

Answer (score 1):

The following code should allow you to save base of the value cell A2

```
Dim FileName    As String
Dim FilePath    As String
FilePath = "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\New folder (2)\"
FileName = Sheets("mailing").Range("A2").Text & ".docx"
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=FilePath & "\" & FileName, _
OriginalFormat:=wdOriginalDocumentFormat
```

Comment: Hi Omar, I trying your code but something´s wrong. I have some error:
Named argument not found by *OriginalFormat*

Comment: The purpose was to save the word document generated after the merge, but thx for contribution